# .NET Windows Form Data to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# .NET Windows Form with text fields.  The user enters data into this form and once they submit I need to generate a PDF file with their data arranged neatly.  What is the best way to do this? Should I move the data into a database or can I directly export to PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add it to a database if you don't want to persist the data for later use. There are tons of libraries out there for pdf creation in c#.

Here's a [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630708/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-pdf-from-c) made not long ago with some great references. It also covers almost the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

you want to export directly to pdf. are you have any specific format, how it should Looks.
otherwise create a **crystal report**. Design a format.After that write this code

```
            Crystalreportobject.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, name + ".pdf");
```

**ExportToDiskMethod** can Export directly to **PDF**